# Jquery draggable when stop create div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, createelement

Okay I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here but the div is not created and I don't know why?

```
$('#tree_01').draggable({appendTo: 'body', helper: 'clone', stop: function(event, ui) {
                var bg_pos_x = -5;
                var bg_pos_y = -1516;
                var width = 148;
                var height = 174;
                var pos_x = $(ui.helper).position().left;
                var pos_y = $(ui.helper).position().top;
                var id = 'tree_'+pos_x+'_'+pos_y;
                folliage(id,bg_pos_x,bg_pos_y,width,height,pos_x,pos_y);
            }});
```

When the draggable element is dropped it should run the code and go to the following function:

```
function folliage(id,bg_pos_x,bg_pos_y,width,height,pos_x,pos_y){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
    document.getElementById(id).style.left=pos_x+'px';
    document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex='5';
    document.getElementById(id).style.left=pos_y+'px';
    document.getElementById(id).style.width=width+'px';
    document.getElementById(id).style.height=height+'px';
    document.getElementById(id).style.background='url(../img/village.png)';
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundPosition=bg_pos_x+'px '+bg_pos_y+'px';

}
```

but the div doesn't get created????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually add the div to the page. You need to use something like `append` to add the div to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, such a silly mistake and I didn't realise it, I spent the past 2 hours trying to figure it out thinking the browsers screwing with my mind :P. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` element *does* get created, but you're never adding it to the DOM tree, so it will never be visible on the page.

You can append the new element to, say, the page body:

```
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

As an aside, your `folliage()` function would be shorter and probably more readable were you to extend your use of jQuery to its code.

Also note that the line:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.left=pos_y+'px';
```

Probably should read:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.top = pos_y + 'px';
```

Comment: do the spaces make a difference? I'm not an expert, just interested :)

Comment: No difference at all, apart from improved readability IMHO :)

Comment: lol, that's true though :) I should make a habit of putting spaces in :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you should use jQuery's element creation methods instead of `document.createElement`. But it looks like your problem is you aren't adding the newly created element to the document. Try using `jQuery('<div id=' + id + '/>').appendTo('body');` or something similar.